# How to enable {% trans %} tag for jinja templates?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, internationalization, jinja2

I try to enable the `trans` tag and I've made a test template i18n.html:

`{% trans %}For sale{% endtrans %}--{{message}}--{{decimal_format}}`
Here is my python code according to the [manpages](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/i18n.html):

```
from webapp2_extras import i18n as multilingua
import jinja2
from webapp2_extras.i18n import lazy_gettext as gettext
from webapp2_extras.i18n import lazy_gettext as _
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
jinja_environment =  jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                      extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'])

# The code below seems wrong since it is django but it was the only way I could make the page load

jinja_environment.install_gettext_translations(django.utils.translation)

class HelloWorldHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Set the requested locale.
        locale = self.request.GET.get('locale', 'pt')
        multilingua.get_i18n().set_locale(locale)
        message = multilingua.gettext('For sale')
        #django.utils.translation.activate('pt')
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/i18n.html')
    decimal_format = multilingua.I18n(self.request).format_decimal(1000)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(message=message, decimal_format=decimal_format))
```

I could not make it work without django and therefore I ask how to lose the django translation and staying with webapp2.i18n + jinja instead.

There was also a discussion in [a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pocoo-libs/gZTQSAc5H2E) where I'm not the only one saying that documentation is somewhat incomplete or hard to find. Could you please answer or comment which is the recommended way of making the trans tag work and why I must include `jinja_environment.install_gettext_translations(django.utils.translation)`
?

When I try to remove my use of django I also lose the functions of webapp2.i18n. My locale files are both in locale/... and conf/locale.. since the first is the default for webapp2 and the second is the default for django translations, so I could really use some guidelines for best practice here to get rid of the django dependecies and use webapp2 and jinja for rendering my localizations.

If to any help, I did receive an error message when trying to remove django:

```
    self.response.out.write(template.render(message=message, decimal_format=decimal_format))
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/montaoproject/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/media/Lexar/montao/montaoproject/templates/i18n.html", line 2, in top-level template code
    {{ _('For sale') }}--{{message}}--{{decimal_format}}
UndefinedError: 'gettext' is undefined
```

Thank you

Comment: Undocumented solution / workaround that makes my jinja trans tags work: `from webapp2_extras import i18n jinja_environment.install_gettext_translations(i18n)`

Comment: It would be interesting to know how you found this undocumented solution / workaround.

Comment: to anyone reading this, here is an up to date guide on how to do this http://mikeshilkov.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/enable-jinja2-and-i18n-translations-on-google-appengine/

Comment: In 2016, the django-jinja package does a good job of handling this: http://niwinz.github.io/django-jinja/latest/#_i18n_support

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at Jinja2's [i18n Extension documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#i18n-extension). Calling `install_gettext_translations` basically sets the object through which Jinja2 will call gettext, ngettext, etc, in order to translate strings when it encounters a `{% trans %}` tag.

Since those functions are defined on `webapp2.i18n` (see [here](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/i18n.html#webapp2_extras.i18n.gettext)), jinja2 will successfully call those functions to retrieve translations, dependent upon your call to `set_locale` inside of the request. I don't have the code in front of me, but I'd guess that `gettext` and company defined in `webapp2.i18n` are merely proxies to call `webapp.i18.get_i18n().gettext`, which is the magic that makes all of this work.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a working example for Django+jinja2:

```
from jinja2 import PackageLoader, Environment 
from django.utils import translation
```

...

```
jinja_environment = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('website', 'templates'),
                                extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'])

jinja_environment.install_gettext_translations(translation)

template = jinja_environment.get_template('test.jinja.html')

page_next_app_table = template.render()
```

...

In test.jinja.html:

```
<html>
<b> {{ _( "Traslate This" ) }}:</b>
</html>
```